# references an unknown entity: java.util.List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dropwizard

Can anyone suggest what I'm missing here? Error occurs on starting a dropwizard application.

The error:

```
web_1       | Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Resource.coordinates references an unknown entity: java.util.List
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
web_1       |   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFactory.buildSessionFactory(SessionFactoryFactory.java:96)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFactory.build(SessionFactoryFactory.java:49)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFactory.build(SessionFactoryFactory.java:39)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle.run(HibernateBundle.java:62)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle.run(HibernateBundle.java:15)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:200)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:42)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
web_1       |   at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
web_1       |   at EdgeApplication.main(EdgeApplication.java:103)
```

Resource class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="EDGE_RESOURCE")
public class Resource {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    private List<Coordinate> coordinates;

    ...
}
```

Referenced Coordinate class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="EDGE_COORDINATE")
public class Coordinate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private double
                latitude,
                longitude;
}
```

It's dropwizard, with dropwizard-guice.

```
public class EdgeApplication extends Application<EdgeConfiguration> {

    public static final HibernateBundle<EdgeConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<EdgeConfiguration>(Coordinate.class, Session.class, Resource.class) {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(EdgeConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDatabase();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void initialize(final Bootstrap<EdgeConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);

        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: You should have used `@OneToMany` instead of `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: Rich: you're not alone!

Comment: @Jesper that works, thank you! I suggest posting it as answer

Answer (score 1):

use @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Entity.class)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).